# How to execute the code generated by codeDom?

Tags: c#-3.0, code-generation, codedom

I just generated the .cs file using codeDom. Can someone explain how do I execute it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not quite that simple. [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx) for a primer.  Basically the CodeDom supports scenarios such as  [code generation and dynamic compilation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/650ax5cx.aspx).  So .cs files created with the CodeDom are not executables in the usual sense.

Answer (score 1):

The code below will allow you to compile the code using the codedom and then you can show the user if the code compiled correctly or not. It even creates a DLL as well.

Thanks
Alex

```
// Store provider from the method into a object, Default is CSharpCodeProvider**
CodeDomProvider provider = this.GetCurrentProvider();

// Configure a CompilerParameters that links System.dll**
String[] referenceAssemblies = { "System.dll", "System.Data.Linq.dll", "System.Web.dll","System.XML.dll","System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll", "System.Data.dll", _mvcLocation };

CompilerParameters cp = new CompilerParameters(referenceAssemblies, this.fileLocation + this.fileName + ".dll", false);

// Generate an executable rather than a DLL file.**

cp.GenerateExecutable = true;

// Invoke compilation.**
CompilerResults _results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromFile(cp, this.fileLocation + this.fileName + "." + this.extention);
```